# Unhandled Rejecttion(Type Error): Cannot Read Property 'Status' Of Undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have an input where if a user searches for id and if it matches the id, it will display the status. But it gives me an error if a user doesn't give the right ID. What should I do so that even if the user searches for invalid it will just display "Invalid id".

[My array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrLSo.png)

[What my code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awY30.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoveflow. Instead sharing an image of a problem or a code please share the problem and code itself. Maybe reproduce a minimal example on codeSanbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, I have seen that 
Array Looks like:

```
let Deliveries=[{DeliveryID:"WHKYYY", OwnerID:2, Staus:"Delivered"},
    {DeliveryID:"MHKYYY", OwnerID:3, Staus:"Delivered"},
    {DeliveryID:"KKHKYYY", OwnerID:4, Staus:"Warehouse"},
    {DeliveryID:"LLHKYYY", OwnerID:2, Staus:"Delivered"},
   ]
```

Problem is that when you are searching for something and it is not matching with the DeliveryID that time search result will be undefined. You can use || to avoid the undefined values to set the empty array like [] and before return the staus you can check the rearch result. If the result is empty return "".

Code like :

```
let track =data.Deliveries.filter(item=> Model.searchQuery===item.DeliveryID)||[];
if(track .length>0){
//mathch the ID and informaiton is avialable
//other code here
}else{
// does not match. return null or ""
}
```